# "Collection was modified;" ... but it wasn't

Tags: vb.net, collections

I have a list of objects:

```
Dim objList As BindingList(Of Object1)
```

Each of those contains a list of Object2. I am trying to iterate through objList so that I can remove specific instances of Object2 from each Object1's respective Object2 list:

```
For Each obj In objList
    Dim objRemove = obj.Object2List.Where(AddressOf ObjCheck)
    For Each obj2 In objRemove
        obj.Object2List.Remove(obj2)
    Next
Next
```

This throws the error, "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."

What I don't understand is that I am removing an object from Object2List, which is not being enumerated. Why is this error being thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `Where` doesn't actually execute a query and create a new collection. It simply creates an iterator that iterates the original list skipping over elements that don't match the query.

You need to add a call to `ToList()` to immediately execute the query and create a new collection of items:

```
Dim objRemove = obj.Object2List.Where(AddressOf ObjCheck).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you are enumerating `Object2List` just indirectly.  The `objRemove` collection internally holds a reference to `Object2List` and enumerating `objRemove` will implicitly also enumerate `Object2List`

The easiest way to work around this is to enumerate the collection by index

```
Dim index = 0
Dim list = obj.Object2List
While index < list.Count
  If ObjCheck list(index) Then
    list.RemoveAt(index)
  Else
    index = index + 1
End
```